# Asymptotic of the positive root of $x^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = 0$

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, roots, golden-ratio

As I'm sure many of you know, the golden ratio is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the positive root of the polynomial $x^2-x-1$. Similarly, the positive root of $x^3-x^2-x-1$ is the tribonacci number $\approx 1.839$. In general the positive root of the polynomial $x^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$ is the ratio $f_{m+1}/f_{m}$ to which the sequence $f_m = \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_{m-k}$ converges.

As we increase $n$ in the polynomial $x^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$, the positive root approaches $2$. I am interested in finding the rate at which this happens.

We can actually considerably simplify this problem by considering that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$ The question then reduces to solving $x^n-\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = 0$. We can get $$x^{n+1}-x^n-(x^n-1) = x^{n+1}-2x^n+1=0$$

The question finally reduces to finding the asymptotic of the positive root of $x^{n+1}-2x^n+1$ (let's call this function $g(n)$).

Any ideas?

Edit: I graphed $\frac{1}{2-g(n)}$ for $n = 1...30$ in python using matplotlib. This looked exponential, so I took the log of it. The log then seemed to converge to $\ln(2)$, giving me an asymptotic of $g(n)=2-2^{-n}$. If anyone could give me more error terms or explain why this is, feel free to do so.

Comment: Try plugging in $x = 2 - \epsilon$ and taking a Taylor series for small $\epsilon$. Keeping only the leading term in $\epsilon$ does indeed yield $\epsilon \approx 2^{-n}$.

Comment: I answered a similar question recently but cannot find it.  I got your answer that $g(n) \approx 2-2^{-n}$  The rest of the roots were distributed close to the unit circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h_n(x)=x^{n+1}-2x^n+1$.  Note that $h_n(2)=1$ and $h_n'(2)=2^n$.  This immediately gives $2-2^{-n}$ as an approximation to the root $g(n)$, by taking a linear approximation to $h_n$ near $2$.

To get bounds on how good this approximation is, note first that $$h_n'(x)=((n+1)x-2n)x^{n-1}$$ is less than $2^n$ for $x$ strictly between $2-2^{-n}$ and $2$ and so actually $g(n)<2-2^n$.  To get a lower bound on $g(n)$, notice that $$h_n'(2-a)=(2-(n+1)a)(2-a)^{n-1}>2^n-na2^n$$ for $0<a<\frac{2}{n+1}$ (here we use the fact that $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)>x^n-x^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ if $0<a_i<x$ for all $i$, which is easily proved by induction on $n$).  In particular, for any fixed $c>1$, then for $n$ sufficiently large, $h_n'(2-a)>2^n/c$ as long as $0<a<c2^{-n}$.  It follows that $h_n(2-c2^{-n})<0$ and so $g(n)>2-c2^{-n}$.

That is, for any $c>1$, we have $$2-c2^{-n}<g(n)<2-2^{-n}$$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  In particular, $\frac{2-g(n)}{2^{-n}}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Shouldn't $h_n'(2-a)=(2-(n+1)a)(2-a)^{n-1}$ be $h_n'(2-a)=-(2-(n+1)a)(2-a)^{n-1}$?

Comment: No.  For sanity-checking, when $a=0$, you should get $h_n'(2)=2^n$.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. Do you know how I could find more error terms? I feel like this method only works for the first one, since it is a linear approximation, not a higher order one.

Comment: Why couldn't it work with a higher order approximation?  You could invert the Taylor approximation of any degree at $2$ to get an approximation to $g(n)$ (though off the top of my head I don't know a systematic way to get useful error bounds on the approximation).

Comment: What do you mean by inverting the Taylor approximation?

Comment: I mean find the inverse function of the Taylor approximation, so you can find its root.  You won't get a closed form for this in general, but you can take the inverse as a power series and cut it off after a certain number of terms to get a closed form approximation to the root.